# Drop down option for factor variables in editable DT in R

Tags: r, dt

Is there a way to restrict editing of a cell to only the factor levels in a `DT` in R?

Here's some sample data:

```
structure(list(boatName = c("Sunny Bay", "STI Solidarity", "STI Rambla", 
"STI La Boca", "STI San Telmo", "STI Esles II", "STI Jardins", 
"SKY", "Steel", "Bahra"), VesselType = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AFRAMAX LR2 POOL", "HANDYMAX POOL", 
"LR1 POOL", "MID RANGE", "MID RANGE POOL"), class = "factor"), 
    IceClass = c("NO", "N/A", "No", "NO", "YES", "YES", "YES", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "-")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

If I run `datatable(df, editable=TRUE)`, I can edit the individual cells. But I would want the values for say, `VesselType` to be restricted only to the factor levels of the variable.

I know `rhandsontable` has this option by specifying `type = "dropdown"` in `hot_col()`, but can this be done in `DT`. And can editing be limited to only a few columns?

Comment: have u tried `rpivotable` ?

Comment: @saisaran had a look but doesn't quite meet my purpose.